# CQL doesn't allow me to read data in a range

Tags: go, cassandra, cql, gocql

I'm using GOCQL to query for data in a range of timestamps. When I query for data <= a certain time, the code below works fine. When I query for data >= a certain time, it again works fine. When I combine both constraints, the returned slice is empty.

```
map := map[string]interface{}{}
read := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM employee_table WHERE user_id=%v AND posttime>='%v' AND posttime<='%v'", user_id, posttimeMin.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000+0000"), posttimeMax.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000+0000"))
    
    iter := Session.Query(query).Iter()
    for iter.MapScan(map) {
        readTable = append(readTable, employee_table{
            user_id: m["user_id"].(int),
            posttime: m["posttime"].(time.Time),
            room: m["room"].(string),
        })
        m = map[string]interface{}{}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it doesn't return anything because your query requires that you have the data entry with **exact value** of `2006-01-02 15:04:05.000+0000` with millisecond precision... When you use `>=` or `<=`, then you should have other entries the smaller or greater than this specific value.  You must to check what values are returned by queries that work.